# How to run project from windows service project

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have 3 projects in my solution:

1. Scheduler (Windows application)
2. WCF Service (WCF)
3. WindowsService (Windows Service)

My Scheduler use WCF Service functions and runs them when Scheduler decide.

All this works fine,and know i add new project  Windows Service that his purpose is to launch Scheduler every time when PC is up, and here I fail.

I never worked with Windows Service sow i am new at this.I added the reference of Scheduler to WindowsService and still can't find the way to run it.

I will be very glad for any help.

Here my code that i tried.

My WindowsService project

```
My namespace WindowsService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

           // Scheduler myscheduler = new Scheduler();  
           // Scheduler.SchedulerForm myForm = new Scheduler.SchedulerForm(); 

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And my Scheduler Project (Main)

```
static void Main()
{
    string step = "";
    try
    {
        ServiceHost client = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfService.Service));
        try
        {
            using (client = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfService.Service)))
            {
                step = "1";
                if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    step = "2";
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(step);
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Faulted state. " + step);
                    client.Abort();

                }

                client.Open();
                SysTrayApp();
                Application.Run();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                step = "Faulted";
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(step);
                client.Abort();
                client = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfService.Service));
            }
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "   " + ex.Source + "   " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of project is "scheduler"? If you want to be able to run it from a windows service it should be a class library.

Comment: `Not working` not telling us much information.

Comment: A windows service can be running even when *no* user is logged in (or when multiple users are logged in). It doesn't have access to any user's desktop and so code talking about forms, message boxes and the system tray doesn't belong anywhere near a windows service.

Comment: You don't need a windows service to start/stop the scheduler. scheduler itself capable of handling these, for example you can set the scheduler to start automatically when machine is booted.

Comment: What do you want? Do you fail on stopping the Windows Service when PC is shutting down? If so, what is the problem entirely?

Comment: Just to re-iterate what @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, typically it's not recommended to use a Windows Service if any sort of GUI is involved. However, there are scenarios where both are needed - see [Interactive Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info.